# User Account activation email using Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create User Registration form . User account will be activated by activation email.
Following error is coming:-

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /register/ Exception Value: Reverse for 'activate' not found. 'activate' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

I followed following links :

https://studygyaan.com/django/how-to-signup-user-and-send-confirmation-email-in-django

https://blog.hlab.tech/part-ii-how-to-sign-up-user-and-send-confirmation-email-in-django-2-1-and-python-3-6/

https://medium.com/@frfahim/django-registration-with-confirmation-email-bb5da011e4ef

```py
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            mail_subject = 'Activate your blog account.'
            message = render_to_string('website/acc_active_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user=user),
            })
            to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            email = EmailMessage(
                mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
            )
            email.send()
            return HttpResponse('Please confirm your email address to complete the registration')
        else:
            for msg in form.error_messages:
                print(form.error_messages[msg])
    else:
        print('in else')
        form = NewUserForm()
    return render(request=request, template_name='website/register.html', context={'form': form})

def activate_account(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_bytes(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponse('Your account has been activate successfully')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Activation link is invalid!')
```

My html file code

```html
{% autoescape off %}
Hi {{ user.username }},
Please click on the link to confirm your registration,
http://{{ domain }}{% url 'activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: Can you post your urls.py?

Answer (score 0):

The code part that throws the error seems to be missing.

> Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /register/ Exception Value: Reverse
>   for 'activate' not found. 'activate' is not a valid view function or
>   pattern name.

This error says that you don't have a url in your urls.py that has name='activate'.

At django 2.x it should look like:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    #...
    path('/register/', activate_account, name='activate'),
    #...
]
```

At django 1.x it should look like:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    #...
    url(r'^register/$', activate_account, name='activate'),
    #...
]
```

As written in the [django manual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls) you must give the url a name to access it with reverse() lookup.